# Is there a "standard" way to publish open source javascript files

Tags: javascript, maven

Coming from the java/maven world where everything goes under a "src/main" folder I looked around to see if a similar approach is followed in javascript. However all the main repo's seem to be following their own. Is there a standard folder structure with which I can publish my javascript files? Is the community at least "leaning" towards some such structure or template?

[JQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)
[Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TJ Holowaychuk started "Component" as a structured way of sharing/deploying UI components with traced dependencies. Similar to the way NPM is for NodeJS modules.

https://github.com/component

Now it seems that [Bower](http://bower.io) is taking over and is the new the way to go.